Typescript | Exclude 'children' when inheriting from an HTMLDivElement?
I have a SplitPane component that takes two children. Whenever the first child's size changes, the other is adjusted to fill the remaining space. This works, but I wanted to extend the interface with some additional, standard properties like className. Rather than add these one at a time as I find I need them, I'd just like to extend from the HTMLDivElement interface.
There is, of course, a conflict: My SplitPane takes two children while an HTMLDivElement takes a collection of children of arbitrary length. I though to use the Exclude interface like so to solve this:
export interface SplitPaneProps extends Exclude<HTMLDivElement, 'children'> {
  direction: 'vertical' | 'horizontal', // top-to-bottom and left-to-right
  children: [ReactNode, ReactNode]
}

Unfortunately, I'm still getting the following Typescript error:
Interface 'SplitPaneProps' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLDivElement'.
  Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
    Type '[ReactNode, ReactNode]' is not assignable to type 'HTMLCollection'.ts(2430)

Am I mis-applying the Exclude interface here? How can I get this to work? Thanks!

Maybe you want Omit<HTMLDivElement, 'children'> instead of Exclude.

You should use Omit instead of Exclude:
export interface SplitPaneProps extends Omit<HTMLDivElement, 'children'> {
  direction: 'vertical' | 'horizontal', // top-to-bottom and left-to-right
  children: [ReactNode, ReactNode]
}

function foo(x: SplitPaneProps) {
    x.children = ... //[ReactNode, ReactNode]
}

Omit removes the specified properties from the original type. After that, you can add whatever to the resulting type.
Difference b/w only Exclude and Omit (Pick & Exclude) Typescript

That was it thanks :) Well, that and I needed to derive from HTMLAttributes :P
